# iphone development: having darker background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opacity, uicolor

In my app, I want to make my background darker. I cant use `background.alpha = (float between 0-1)` since it only makes it lighter. What I need is having a background like all the colors are darker like having a filter. How can I do that?

Comment: simple....use darker background.....

Comment: make a very dark image :D add it to background. or change background color to something very dark.

Comment: alpha is for making the background transparant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a overlay view on top of your background view which is black and play with the alpha channel to decide how much dark you want your background to be.

Comment: Damn it ! I think you answered about 10 seconds before me :)

Answer (score 1):

Set your background to black, add a UIImageView on top of it with a white background, and act on the UIImage' alpha. At 1, you'll have a white background, on 0, it will be black. Also works with other colors !

Answer (score 1):

My preferred tactic would be to [getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/getHue%3asaturation%3abrightness%3aalpha%3a) of the background and then derive a new background color by reducing the brightness.

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful macro for setting color with more flexibility than `UIColor`:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

You can then use normal hex values (ie from photoshop or most color picker type controls) to set your background color or any other color, ie

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x6f99d5);
```